# Aut($C_p) = C_{p-1}$when $p$ is prime, why?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, prime-numbers, cyclic-groups

Aut($C_p) = C_{p-1}$ when $p$ is prime, why?

I don't see why this result follows, I'm sure it's obvious though.
I appreciate that Aut($C_p)$ will be of order p-1

Comment: It's easy to show that the order is $p-1$, but it's a little harder to show that is is cyclic.

Comment: To show it is cyclic, note that ${\rm Aut}(C_p)$ is isomorphic to the multiplicative group of the finite field ${\mathbb Z}_p$, and multiplicative groups of finite fields are cyclic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [$\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z_n)$ is isomorphic to $U_n$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186337/operatornameaut-mathbb-z-n-is-isomorphic-to-u-n). See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070057/automorphisms-in-z-n.

Comment: @DietrichBurde this is not a duplicat as it does not show the group is cycclic in that case; one might rather use something like http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807290/proof-of-existence-of-primitive-roots as dupe

Comment: @DietrichBurde But the earlier post did not ask for a proof that it was cyclic.

Comment: It is a duplicate, since $U(C_p)=C_p^{\ast}$ is cyclic.

Comment: @DietrichBurde well yes, but the point of the question is how to prove this.

Comment: Well, OK, I see. Still, I think this question also has appeared at MSE.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I cannot see any reference to that fact in the earlier post.

Comment: Here it is: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625633/automorphism-group-of-bf-z-p.

Answer (score 2):

Pick a fixed generating element $e$. Every endomorphism $f$ is uniquely determined by the image of this generating element $f(e)$.

The image of the generating element $f(e)$ must  be generating to have an automorphism. 
There are thus $p-1$ possibilities for $f(e)$; every element but the neutral one.

To show that the group is cyclic it is best to consider $C_p$ as a field. 
Derek Holt already mentioned a general result that would imply this.

To prove it denote by $t$ the maximal multiplicative order; each non-zero elements multiplicative order is a divisor of it. So each nonzero element is a solution of $X^t=1$. Yet since $X^t-1$ can have at most $t$ roots, we get $t=p-1$, and thus an element of order $p-1$.

Comment: But you still need to show that the automorphism group is cyclic.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out; I did not read the question sufficiently carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Write $C_p=\{e,x,x^2,...,x^{p-1}\}$ where $e$ is the identity element. An automorphism is by definition an isomorphism and an endomorphism, which can be thought of as a relableing of $C_p$ such that $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ (where $f$ is any given automorphism in question). Let's construct a specific automorphism as follows: Let $f$ be an automorphism. Then by properties of homomorphisms, $f(e)=e$. Now assume $f(x)=x^a$ where $a$ is a primitive root. Then $f(x^n)=f(x)^n=(x^a)^n=x^{an}$. Then by composing $f$ with itself, we get that since $a$ is a primitive root, for all $0<n<p$ there is an $0<m<p-1$, $(f^m)(x)=x^n$, hence this process gives all automorphisms and we can check that all of these compositions of $f$ are automorphisms.